# Unity 2D Flip Horizontal Position Problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, scale, flip

firstly sorry for my english; is there a more accurate way to change the scale where the character is located? As you can see, when the scale changes, the position of the character changes. Not fixed.

my flip codes;

```
    if (MoveInput > 0)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
    else if (MoveInput < 0)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
```

[2dgif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvpPq.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that is happening because you don't have your sprite pivots set up correctly.
Go to the sprite, click Sprite Editor and then move your pivots (the blue circles) to the center of the image.

[image: gif]

Comment: obligatory: that fixed for me. It seems the sprite editor for multiple were splitting big empty spaces, so I let it split automatically and corrected some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(MoveInput > 0)
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
}
else if(MoveInput < 0)
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
}
```

[SpriteRenderer Component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html)

Comment: This solution not worked but thank you for your answer

Comment: `transform.localScale.x *= -1;` and `spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX` do different things, but will almost always provide the same result.